# line bundles over affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quasiprojectiveness of bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46895/quasiprojectiveness-of-bundle)

Let L be the total space of an algebraic line bundle over an affine variety (over C).
Is L an affine variety?

Comment: This sounds familiar...


Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46895/quasiprojectiveness-of-bundle/46899#46899.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The natural morphism to the affine variety is an affine morphism and composition of affine morphisms is affine. Alternatively see Hartshorne Ex.II.5.17(a).